# jQuery adding table dynamically

Tags: jquery

I am trying to dynamically add a table using jQuery. In this I am adding a table dynamically on the click event of button (View Budget) by using `$('#ss').text('txt')`. Why is it not working?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Money Management</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=yes;" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="experiments/themeswitcher/jquery.mobile.themeswitcher.js"></script>
        <SCRIPT language="javascript" src="final.js"></SCRIPT>
        <SCRIPT language="javascript" src="validation3.js"></SCRIPT>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
        <SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function tree()
        {
            alert("hello");
            var txt="";
            var myTable="";
            txt+="<table id='myTable' border='5'>";
            txt+="<tr>";
            txt+="<th>"Hello"</th>";
            txt+="<th>"Hello"</th>";
            txt+="</tr>";
            txt+="</table>";
            //$('#aa').tex('Hello World');
            $('#ss').text('txt');
            //document.getElementById('ss').innerHTML = "Hello World";
            //$('body').append('<table id="myTable"><tr>Hello</tr></table>');
        }
        </SCRIPT>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="viewT" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
            <div id="header" data-role="header">
                <h1>Monthly Budget sheet</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content" data-role="content">
                <div id="TableV" data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <form name="budgetSheet" method="post">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="mchoose">Select Month</label></td>
                                <td><select id="mchoose" name="mchoose">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
                                    <option value="January">January</option>
                                    <option value="Febraruary">Febrarury</option>
                                    <option value="March">March</option>
                                    <option value="April">April</option>
                                    <option value="May">May</option>
                                    <option value="June">June</option>
                                    <option value="July">July</option>
                                    <option value="August">August</option>
                                    <option value="September">September</option>
                                    <option value="October">October</option>
                                    <option value="November">November</option>
                                    <option value="December">December</option>
                                    </select></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="Yview">Enter Desired Year</label></td>
                                <td><input id=Yview type="text" placeholder="Enter in YYYY format"/></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="Uview">Select View Type</label></td>
                                <td><select id="Uview" >
                                    <option value="select">Select</option>
                                    <option value="expenses5">Expenses per Month</option>
                                    <option value="category5">Category Expenses per Month</option>
                                </select></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td><input
                                 type="button"
                                 data-role="button"
                                 id="click"
                                 value="View Budget"
                                 onclick="$( tree );"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="ss"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean for you? Describe exactly what's happening, and how it differs from what you want to happen.

Comment: I want that it should replace the div tag with the table as soon as I click the button. Only Table is not showing on the button click event. alert box is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance it looks like you want `.html()` and not `.text()`

```
$('#ss').html(txt);
```

Also your tree() function has an error as well.

This:

```
txt+="<th>"Hello"</th>";
txt+="<th>"Hello"</th>";
```

Should be as you need to treat your content as part of your string.:

```
txt+="<th>Hello</th>";
txt+="<th>Hello</th>";
```

**Update**

Instead of using the onclick simply wire up your click handler with jQuery:

```
$("input.viewBudget").click(tree);
```

Note: I added a class of `viewBudget` to your button.

```
<input type="button" data-role="button" id="click" class="viewBudget" value="View Budget"/>
```

If you ***must use*** the `onclick` you just need to have it supply the onclick with the function name like so:

```
<input class="viewBudget" type="button" data-role="button" id="click" value="View Budget" onclick="tree();">
```

*But also note*, the function *can not* be declared inside of the `ready()` function or you will have some scoping issues.

Also:

> . I want that it should replace the
>   div tag with the table as soon as I
>   click the button

If you want to completely remove `<div id="ss"></div>` you can use `replaceWith()`

```
 $('#ss').replaceWith(txt);
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/P4ucb/4/).**

Comment: still it is not working. Alert Box is working fine. But appending of table is not working.. I want that it should replace the div tag with the table as soon as I click the button. Only Table is not showing on the button click event

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I can see it is working on jsfiddle. But not on my server. I don't know why. This is my link on my server  [link](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~verma1/Assignment3/tracker.html#budgetsheet.html). And I did same thing as you told me. But still alert box is working fine not html table. Any idea why is it happening.

Comment: Ahhh homework `:)` Anyways, `tree()` is defined on `Tracker.html` & `budgetsheet.html`. if you go directly to http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~verma1/Assignment3/budgetsheet.html it shows the table, just remove `tree()` from tracker and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the quotes!

```
$('#ss').text(txt);
```

But I think you want to achieve the result of this:

```
$('#ss').html(txt);
```

Comment: still it is not working dude. Alert Box is working fine. But appending of table is not working.. I want that it should replace the div tag with the table as soon as I click the button. Only Table is not showing on the button click event.